# center of mass for ROI in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, roi

I have an Nifti file of ROIs that is a 192 x 192 x 12 array and want to be able to find the center of mass of the whole thing as well as each of the 12 slices. i am using

```
cm = join(dname, 'cardiac_roi.nii')
roi_img = nib.load(cm)
roi_data = roi_img.get_data()
CM = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(roi_data)
```

and I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

same thing happens when I also try just one slice

```
CM = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(roi_data[:,:,1])
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: What does `print(type(roi_idata))` show?

Comment: class 'numpy.core.memmap.memmap' 

I don't know what that means.

Comment: `numpy.memmap` is a subclass of `numpy.ndarray` that allows memory-mapped arrays (that is, objects that *behave* just like a regular NumPy array, but have their data stored on disk instead of in RAM).  It looks like you've discovered that `center_of_mass` doesn't work for `memmap` instances.  Try converting `roi_data` to a regular `ndarray` first:  `CM = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(numpy.array(roi_data))`

Comment: This may also be worth a NumPy/SciPy bug report.

Comment: Just to complete the info: Nifti is a standard neuroimaging format. Reading it with python has some quirks: The standard library for doing this, `nibabel`, will return a `memmap` onto the data that was written to disk as bulk, usually in f-contiguous ordering. However, the standard nifti format can also take the form of `.nii.gz`, in which case all data are read into memory when calling `get_data`, because gzip does not seem to be seekable. So depending on something as simple as the filename, this data type will turn into a memmap or not. Calling `.copy()` on it or `np.array(...)` as you ...

Comment: ... describe is therefore a good way to homogenize this, provided that data are meant to go into memory anyway. (This is independent from the apparent scipy.ndimage bug). Also, props to @Sidney for using python in neuroimaging ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by replacing the line:

```
CM = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(roi_data)
```

with the lines:

```
import numpy  # Unnecessary if you've already done this.
CM = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(numpy.array(roi_data))
```

Explanation: from your comments, `roi_data` is a NumPy [memory-mapped array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).  The `ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass` function expects a regular NumPy array; that is, an instance of `ndarray`. In theory, since a memory-mapped array has type `memmap`, and `memmap` is a subclass of `ndarray`, your original code should work; in practice it fails (as you've discovered), and the workaround is to explicitly convert the memory-mapped array to a normal NumPy array.  The fact that your code doesn't work represents a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and indicates a bug in either NumPy or SciPy (most likely the former).

Looking at the `ndimage` source, I tracked the difference in behaviour down to the fact that for a memory-mapped array `x`, the result of `x.sum()` is another (zero-dimensional) array, while for a regular NumPy `ndarray` `x`, the result of `x.sum()` is a scalar (an instance of `numpy.float64`, for example).  This NumPy [bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/667) looks relevant.

Comment: great that fixed it! thank you so much for the helpful explanation as to what was going on as well!